# Need to brainstorm some ideas for high performance overflow detector

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Problem:
I have a large table, with say 20 columns, and 150 rows. The columns can be resized by the user (think excel). Each cell has overflow:hidden set.

- When text overflows in any given **cell** i want to give a hint to the user that this is happening.

Constraints:

- This must perform well on IE6. Meaning that if you do this on IE6, you wont want to kill someone while using it.

Comment: IE6... really ? I guess someone is gonna kill someone while developing it.

Comment: what doesnt kill you makes you stronger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i ended up using. it works in IE only, but that is ok in this case:

add this css rule to the container that has overflow:hidden

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

Answer (score 0):

Preface: I have no idea how (or if) this will perform in IE6.

There are probably other ways to do this but you could use nested elements and compare their offsetHeight attributes:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            td { width: 80px; border: 1px solid #000; }
            td div { height: 20px; overflow: hidden; }
            .highlight { background-color: #efe; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><div><span>A B C</div></span></td>
                <td><div><span>D E F G H I J</span></div></td>
                <td><div><span>K L M</span></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div><span>N O P</span></div></td>
                <td><div><span>Q R S</span></div></td>
                <td><div><span>T U V W X Y Z</span></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready
            (
                function()
                {
                    $("td div").each
                    (
                        function()
                        {
                            var collapsedHeight = $(this).attr("offsetHeight");
                            var actualHeight = $("span", this).attr("offsetHeight");

                            // if the inner span is taller than the div, make the div green
                            if (actualHeight > collapsedHeight)
                                $(this).addClass("highlight");
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        </script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to amortize the overflow detection by (for example) writing to a custom property everytime the user inputs data into a cell.

So, you would be using an approach similar to `Lobstrosity`'s but instead of calculating overflow initially you would be calculating overflow each time a cell's input changes. This has the obvious drawback of not working for pre-populated cells, in this situation way you will have to calculate it for all populated cells at program startup.

Another **hardcore** option is to fix the cell dimensions (in other words, assuming the cell dimensions are known at page-generation-time) and calculate the overflow on server-side page generation (assuming you are using a server-side language). Its fugly, but it works.